# Find a column in SQL developer and move that column to the beginning.

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL developer and I have tables with lots of rows, some with more than 40 rows.

I spend a lot of time looking for columns I am interested in a table and dragging it all the way to the left, one at a time.

Is there a shortcut to find a column in the view I have provided here in the picture and when I find it move it all the way to the left.

I understand I can just do `"Select column_name, column_name from table"` and this will do the trick but most of the time I don't even know what the name of the columns are until I look at the data first.

[image: SQL Developer]

Comment: Not sure if you can "find" a column by name in easy way, however, do you know, that you can right-click on column header and select Columns... from context menu. Then you have the list of all the columns in one scrollable box, with buttons to arrange their order (including "Move to the top" button)? Sounds better than columns scrolling left and right...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follow:

1) Execute query with option "Execute script" or F5.

2) This generates text output, so you can search desired column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to alias table and use `Select column_name, column_name from table` approach such a way:

1. `select t.* from table t`
2. need to view `rank` first
3. `select t.rank, t.* from table t`
4. need `ontime_performance` also
5. `select t.rank, t.ontime_performance, t.* from table t`

and so on ...